# Is it possible to make an interface where the return type of a method is not specified?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I find it hard to describe this in English because it is not my first language so I hope the question/title makes sense.

I need to know if I can make an interface with a method which can return any type in the implementation.

I want to make a generic mapper that I can inject into another class. But I am wondering if I can make a generic mapper or if I need to make different interfaces for the different types. It looks pointless to me to make different interfaces which do the same but only have different return types?

sort of like this:

```
public interface IMapper()
{
    T MapObject() where T = the return type
    List<T> MapList() where T = the return type;
}

public class OrderMapper : IMapper()
{
   OrderDetails MapObject()
   {
      mapping code...
      return OrderDetails;
   }
}

public class CustomerMapper : IMapper()
{
    CustomerDetails MapObject()
    {
        mapping code...
        return CustomerDetails;
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do? Or am I just being obtuse and do I need to make different interfaces.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy When you edit a title, please make sure you check [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) on whether tags should be in titles at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) are exactly what you need:

```
public interface IMapper<T>
{
    T MapObject();
    List<T> MapList();
}

public class OrderMapper : IMapper<OrderDetails>
{
    public OrderDetails MapObject()
    {
        //  mapping code...

        return new OrderDetails();
    }

    public List<OrderDetails> MapList()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CustomerMapper : IMapper<CustomerDetails>
{
    public CustomerDetails MapObject()
    {
        //  mapping code...

        return new CustomerDetails());
    }

    public List<CustomerDetails> MapList()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Argh, you beat me to it :) Exact same code and reference link!

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I needed!